# Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: jquery, date-conversion

I'm getting a date result from an API in the format yyyy-mm-dd (plus unwanted hh-mm-ss).
I want to convert this to a dd-mm-yyyy format in jQuery, whats the easiest/quickest way?

At the moment I'm using: (for returned string yyyy-mm-dd):

```
var year = results.job.posted.substr(0,4);
var month = results.job.posted.substr(5,2);
var day = results.job.posted.substr(8,2);
$('#job-date').text(day+'-'+month+'-'+year);
```

but it seems a bit long winded.

Comment: Maybe: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat but.. what did you try?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your `substr` approach, FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want it as a *string* in that format just chop it up and rearrange;

```
var d = "yyyy-mm-dd XXX";
d = d.substr(0, 10).split("-");

d = d[2] + "-" + d[1] + "-" + d[0];
```

Comment: Greate Straightforward Answer.  Thank You, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date_old //your old date in yyyy-mm-dd
var date = dateFormat(new Date(date_old), 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have date object then you can use

```
var date_Obj = new Date(last_modified);
var newDate = date_Obj .getFullYear() + "-" + date_Obj.getMonth() + "-" + date_Obj.getDate() + "T" + date_Obj.getHours() + ":" + date_Obj.getMinutes() + ":" + date_Obj.getSeconds()
```

or you can follow [Convert string to date in Javascript /Jquery](http://rajeshstutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/convert-string-to-date-in-javascript.html)